# The method getTtrackOrderUrl in order history page is depricated?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipment

In template All Files

> ../app/design/frontend/default/default/template/sales/order/history.phtml

exist string

```
<?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
```

method in block

> Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History

there code

```
public function getTrackUrl($order)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/track', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

but in controller

> Mage_Sales_OrderController

action named `trackAction()` is not exist

Anybody know **why method to get Url exist but action does not exist?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most recent version of Magento, **the tracking is handled via a popup.**

The relevant code can be found under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/view.phtml` :

```
    <?php if ($_order->getTracksCollection()->count()) : ?>
        <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>','trackorder','top=0,left=0,width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Track your order')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track your order') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The `getTrackUrl()` method still exists but is not used anymore. Removing code is not great in software development, I reckon the Magento team should have kept the `trackAction()` method and marked both methods as deprecated